# return class extending generic trait in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, scala-generics

Scala code:

```
trait Converter[S, T] {
  def convert(source: S): T
}

class StringDuplicatorConverter extends Converter[Integer, String] {
  override def convert(source: Integer): String = {
    source.toString + source.toString
  }
}

// whatever, the point is to show potentially many 'converters'
// from Integer (for example) to something
class SomeOtherConverter extends Converter[Integer, User] {
  override def convert(source: Integer): User = {
    User(source)
  }
}

trait ConverterProvider {
  def getConverter[N]: Converter[Integer, N]
}

class MyClass extends ConverterProvider {
  override def getConverter[N]: Converter[Integer, N] = {
    new StringDuplicatorConverter()
  }
}
```

gives

```
Error:(17, 5) type mismatch;
 found   : StringDuplicatorConverter
 required: Converter[Integer,N]
    new StringDuplicatorConverter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may* be that what you really want is for each `ConverterProvider` to provide a converter to a specific type (otherwise the definition of `MyClass` doesn't make much sense: it should return different converters for different `N`, not always `StringDuplicatorConverter`). If so, the correct definition is

```
trait ConverterProvider[N] {
  def getConverter: Converter[Integer, N]
}

class MyClass extends ConverterProvider[String] {
  override def getConverter: Converter[Integer, String] = {
    new StringDuplicatorConverter()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A call to `getConverter[N]` is supposed to return something of type `Converter[Integer,N]` but `StringDuplicatorConverter` is type `Converter[Integer,String]`. Since `N` is not restricted to `String`, and thus they are different types, this won't compile.

If the compiler were given some guarantee that `N` is a, or super-type of, `String` then it would work. This can be done by making the return type covariant ...

```
trait Converter[S, +T] { ...
```

... and then defining `getConverter`, and the override, like this:

```
def getConverter[N >: String]: Converter[Integer, N]
```

Now it compiles and appears to work.

```
val mc = new MyClass
mc.getConverter.convert(7)  // res0: String = 77
```